# Struggling to navigate styling on React

Tags: css

I'm extremely new to this stuff, so please don't judge.

I'm trying to build a website and now I'm at the css part of it. My text is showing up in a different color than what I chose, its in the middle and its supposed to be on the left, I added a Menu icon but that's nowhere to be seen and I've added sections in the menu, also nothing.

I feel like crying.

I'm following an instructional and the code is exactly the same, but its showing up different on my side.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {Link as LinkR} from 'react-router-dom'
import { findByLabelText } from '@testing-library/dom';
import {Link as LinkS} from 'react-scroll'

export const Nav = styled.nav`
    background: #000;
    height: 80px; 
    /*margin-top: -80px; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1rem; 
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        transition: 0.8s all ease;
    }
`

export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1'
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 24px;
    max-width: 1100px;
`

export const NavLogo = styled(LinkR)`
color: red;
justify-self: flex-start;
cursor: pointer; 
font-size: 1.5rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin-left: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
`;

export const MobileIcon = styled.div`
display:none;

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: o;
    right: 0;
    transfrom: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000; 
}
`
export const NavMenu = styled.ul`
    display: flex;
    align-itens: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: -22px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        display: none;
    }
`

export const NavItem = styled.li`
    height: 80px;
`

export const NavLinks = styled (LinkS)`
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    &.active {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it solves your problem, but:

In your code at the NavbarContainer after you set the z-index you have a quote instead of a semicolon.
And also at the NavMenu you wrote align-itens instead of align-items.

If you are using VSCode then install the following extension: vscode-styled-components

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am on VS Code. Just curious if you think its a problem that it doesn't bring up any suggestions when I'm doing the styling? basically when i define any attributes, the text is all the same color and no suggestions pop up while I'm typing

Comment: The fixes helped with the block and text alignment, color is still wrong. Menu bar also showed up, alignment is just a little off

Comment: The extension was a recommendation because it helps you to avoid these types of typos.

Comment: I took a look at it and found that at the NavLinks you wrote &.active instead &:active. For me the color what you set is right (it's white), but if it helps then here's a little snippet (keep in mind if your screen is smaller than 768px then the links will diappear):
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-darkness-p84fq?file=/src/styled.js